# How can I separate one sentence between two different <div>s, such that both parts of the sentence are always on the same line?

Tags: html, css

So I just taught myself HTML & CSS and I am trying to create my own website at the moment. Right now I have two different `<div>`s with the same height, side by side (one on the left, the other on the right). I want to write something in the first `<div>`, and continue the rest in the second `<div>`. 
More specifically, I want to write a description of an item in the first `<div>`, and the price of that item in the second `<div>`.

I am having trouble keeping them on the same line, with respect to each other. So if the description moves down or up, the price moves with it.

Many Thanks for your time and effort with me!

Comment: It KIND of sounds like you need to use a `table`. Are you sure this isn't tabular data?

Comment: No its not exactly tabular data. So my example wasn't good enough to reflect what I meant. I am creating my webpage for my resume. So I would like to put my experiences in one <div> , and the dates of the experiences in the second <div> respectively. To add, I would like to have a third <div> on the left side that acts as a table of content for my resume.

Comment: So, by same line, do you just mean that you want the divs to move together?  Wrap them all in a container div.

Comment: What is this shady question? First you are very generic, then you say you want an item description and price in the divs, then in the comments you say you want resume experience and dates in the divs...

Comment: Yea am sorry, I realized what I did there. I did not know I could edit my original post. I'll make sure to think out my question/answer properly before posting.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class='item_container'>
  <div class='experience'>I did lots of shit</div>
  <div class='projects'>Here's some of it</div>
</div>
```

Then you can position the item_container div and style the interior divs as appropriate.

Still, tables can be the way to go.  HTML tables are a little more than just what we think of when we hear table--it's not just excel.

```
<table>
<tr> 
  <th>Item</th>
  <th>Price</th> 
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Cheese</td>
  <td>$2</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Note:  the th (table-head) isn't necessary.  Just nice.  Depends on your use case.

Comment: exactly I thought the same think

Comment: Now my problem with this is that if I have a heading in the first <div>  and the second line in the same <div>is the first listing for my experience,  the date corresponding to the first listing in the second <div> will be in the same line as the heading as opposed to being in line with the first listing.

Comment: You can nest as many divs as you like.  I don't quite understand what you're going for, but you can wrap up as many divs and container-divs (same thing) as you like.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="left">
        item
    </span>
    <span class="right">
        des
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container
{
    width:100%;
    min-height:20px;
    background-color:gray;
}

.left
{
    width:48%;
    padding:1%;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
}

.right
{
    width:48%;
    padding:1%;
    background-color:aqua;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[HERE IS THE FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/hZsEH/)

Answer (score 0):

I see, There are various methods to fix this issue.

```
first one is you can use `display:table` to align the div content

second one is you can `float` property and parent div must use `overflow:hidden`

third option is you can use `vertical align:top` if both div have same height and width.
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe give them the same class or id.

```
<div class="sameinboth"></div>
<!-- Or... -->
<div id="sameinboth"></div>
```

And then your css with a class or id selector:

```
.class {

}
#div {

}
```

Comment: This won't work because I forgot to mention that there will be a third div on the left side. The two side <div> have the same size and width, but the middle one is bigger and wider.

Comment: You also can't have more than one thing with the same id.